# How do I lazy load images on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, lazy-loading, shopify-template

I need to load all the Shopify images through lazyload.

Comment: you need to use any 3rd JS lib to load images on demand, most of the Shopify default and paid theme already have the same JS libs already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the lazy load script and the class for the same.

Here are the steps that you can follow:

**Step 1: Add the Lazy Load script to the Shopify store**

From your Shopify admin, go to **Online Store > Themes**.

Find the theme you want to edit, and then click **Actions > Edit code**.

In the **Layouts** directory, click themes.liquid to open it in the online code editor.

In the online code editor, add the below code before close  tag.

```
{{ '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js' | script_tag }}
```

Click **Save**.

**Step 2: Indicate the images to lazy load**

Add the class lazyload to images that should be lazy loaded. In addition, change the src attribute to data-src.

**Before**

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

**After**

```
<img class="lazyload" src="img path" data-src="image.jpg" />
```

**Step 3: Instantiate Lazy Load in your JS document**

Add the below Javascript code to your **.js or .js.liquid** file in the **Assets** directory and you are done.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("img.lazyload").lazyload();

});
```